# SQL Server : GROUP error

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a problem in SQL Server. I have a table name `rTable` and inside many columns of different types (Date, XML, varchar and so..)

Now I need group by one of this columns.

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM rTable
GROUP BY integer_column
```

But this query give me error.

In MySQL it working normaly, but SQL Server asking me for do some operation in group with another columns, I need just show it.

What is recomendation?

Comment: In SQL Server you can only select only columns present in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Please select the same column in select on which group by is based.

Comment: Found solution 

`SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM rTable
WHERE 
 integer_column IN (
 SELECT integer_column
  FROM rTable
 GROUP BY integer_column
 )
`

Comment: @RashadAliyev Then what is use of Group by? It will list all record.

Comment: @Rashad Aliyev: That "solution" makes no sense. The IN clause is TRUE for *all* records of course. You are merely selecting 100 random records. It could even be 100 records with all the same integer_column, but you want just *one* record per integer_column (therefore the GROUP BY clause in your original query).

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner Yes, I see. It not working correctly.

Comment: @RashadAliyev Agreed with Thorsten. You don't achieve anything if you specify all fields in select clause with group by.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya YEs iT's incorrect :( What is solution?

Comment: @RashadAliyev Solution is mention in my answer below. By the way what do you want to achieve by group by?

Comment: @JenishRabadiya What about text and another types?

Comment: @Rashad Aliyev: I start to wonder whether you know what yor MySQL query is actually doing, so I've added an elaboration to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can not select all the column with group by clause in MS SQL.

```
SELECT integer_column, count(integer_column)
FROM rTable
GROUP BY integer_column
```

and also can use aggregate function like count, sum in select clause if you wanted.

Comment: But another columns is Text, XML, datetime. What do with this columns?

Comment: What about text and another types?

Comment: @RashadAliyev I think what you are looking for is order by try like `SELECT FROM rTable ORDER BY integer_column`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is not a limitation of MS SQL (although it has many), but it is conforming to the SQL standard.

You have to name all columns in the GROUP BY clause, except those using an aggregate function.

Comment: But i don't need group by all. i need group by id. @holger-jakobs

Answer (score 0):

You are using two MySQL extensions that don't work in SQL Server.

In Standard SQL each column selected in an aggregation query must either be in the GROUP BY clause (`integer_column` in your case) or get aggregated (such as `max(other_column)`). You select * instead, so you select integer_column *and* other_column in this example. In MySQL you simply get a random match for other_column in the group. In SQL Server you get a syntax error instead.

Then: MySQL extends GROUP BY, so that it is guaranteed to get the records in the order specified in GROUP BY. In Standard SQL you must add an ORDER BY clause to be sure to get the records in the desired order. TOP without ORDER BY might give you 100 random records.

Something like this would work:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
  integer_column,
  MIN(other_column) AS other_column
FROM rTable
GROUP BY integer_column
ORDER BY integer_column;
```

EDIT: I wonder whether you know what yor MySQL query is actually doing, so I think I'd better elaborate. Let's say your table only contains three columns integer_column, cola, and colb. And let's further say your table has just three records:

```
integer_column  cola  colb
1                a1    b1
1                a2    b2
2                a3    b3
```

Your query picks the lowest 100 integer_column. In this example exist just two: 1 and 2, so both are picked. Then per integer_column the query picks random cola and colb. Your result may look like this:

```
integer_column  cola  colb
1                a2    b1
2                a3    b3
```

(It usually won't. The dbms will play it easy and pick values from one record only, either the first or the last, so you probably get either 1-a1-b1 or 1-a2-b2, but there is no guarantee to that.)

Having said this, you will get the lowest integer_column along with indeterminate values. In Standard SQL you can use MIN or MAX, to get a value. It doesn't matter if you use MIN(cola) which is a1 or MAX(cola) which is a2, as you don't care anyhow.

Comment: No, this is not good solution for current problem. In TAble have Another fields also.

Comment: You must specify an aggregation for *every* column of course. So if there is another column called yet_another_column, you must use MIN or MAX on it, too. (Whether `MIN(yet_another_column)` or `MAX(yet_another_column)` doesn't matter for you, as you don't care, as your original query shows.)

Comment: You must specify an aggregation for *every* column of course. So if there is another column called yet_another_column, you must use MIN or MAX on it, too. (Whether `MIN(yet_another_column)` or `MAX(yet_another_column)` doesn't matter for you, as you don't care, as your original query shows.)

Comment: Problem on text and another types.

Comment: What problem? MIN and MAX should work with any type.